# Use vertices from one low polycount 3D object to position many ThreeJs geometry objects in a scene

Tags: 3d, vertices

How can I use the vertices data of a low polycount 3D object to position other objects in a scene?

I want to animate and tween geometry objects in a scene to match the shape of several low polycount models.

When I try to import the vertices data or the attributes.positions.array data from an object, the math does not quite work out.

I tried doing the following for each vert:

```
let vx = arr[0];
let vy = arr[1];
let vz = arr[2];
let scale = 50;
let d = 1 / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx, 2) + Math.pow(vy, 2) + Math.pow(vz, 2));
vx *= d*scale;
vy *= d*scale;
vz *= d*scale;
let v3 = new THREE.Vector3(vx,vy,vz)
```

But the shapes are a bit wonky.

My guess is that I need to incorporate normals info.